# Do I need a MacBook to write software for iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Currently, I use Ubuntu as my OS.
What do I need to write iPhone software. A MacBook? Or some drivers in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes...You will need to run Mac OSX using the Xcode IDE and you will also need to register as an Apple Developer. You will be able to register for free which will allow you to download the Xcode IDE, but to be able to submit and test applications you will have to pay a $99 registration fee which gives you access to many more things such as the Apple Developer Forums...

Comment: this is the only reason i haven't yet started to mess with iphone development too... Much easier to get started for free w/ android without all of the 'needing Max OSx stuff...

Comment: Note that there are a few convenient, albeit EULA-conflicting, ways to run retail Mac OSX on arbitrary hardware. Search Google for OSx86.

Comment: You can always hackintosh !!! ;)